# catkin_make clean

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a  way to clean a certain package with catkin_make?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138731/catkin_make-clean/) by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to do that is to delete the build folder for the package. Usually that is `build/<package_name>`. However, the package places generated files in the `devel` folder, and those are not as easily cleared out because they are mixed in with the generated files from other packages. The most sure fire way is to delete the `devel` folder and the `build` folder, but deleting just the `build/<package_name>` folder and the `devel` folder might still work and be faster.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2